# How calculate hashCode of a Pojo by combining hashCodes of it's keys

Tags: java, hashcode, pojo

Consider i have one POJO having String class members :

```
class POJO {
  String name, address, emailId;
  equals() {

  }
  hashCode() {
    // How?    
  }
}
```

How can i combine `hashCode`s of my strings to form a `hashCode` for POJO?

Comment: `return 31 + 7 * name.hashCode() + 11 * address.hashCode()//...etc`

Comment: eclipse: `Source --> Generate hashCode() and equals()` ...

Comment: Netbeans: `Alt + Insert --> Generate hashCode() and equals()`

Comment: highly possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2730865/544983

Comment: you really dont need to worry about these as IDE can generate it for you

Answer (score 36):

Java 7 has a utility method to create a hashcode which is good for most uses:

```
return Objects.hash(name, address, emailId);
```

You still need to make sure that your equals method is consistent. The two methods could look like:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, address, emailId);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    final POJO other = (POJO) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) return false;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.address, other.address)) return false;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.emailId, other.emailId)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) class without worrying about hashcode implementation.It follows the contract between *hashcode* and *equals*.
For your class you have to do implementation like the following.

```
@Override    
public int hashCode(){
    HashCodeBuilder builder = new HashCodeBuilder();
    builder.append(name);
    builder.append(address);
    builder.append(emailId);
    return builder.toHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty decent hashcode below.

```
   @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.address);
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.emailId);
        return hash;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
public int hashCode()
{
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result
                    + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
            result = prime * result
                    + ((emailId == null) ? 0 : emailId.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
            return result;
}
```

Comment: What are you adding on `prime * result` repeatedly? I think this doesn't add anything to the `hashCode`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Just to make hashcode unique.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613102/why-use-a-prime-number-in-hashcode

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to use a prime number, but to multiply each not addition to the `hashCode`, not scale the `hashCode` repeatedly by prime numbers. So `result += 7 * address`. Also use different primes for each field that way if two fields have values swapped the hashCode is more likely to be unique.

Comment: Generally people use hashcode with equals.